# Is there software to help with consolidating/combining/deduplicating contacts for the iPhone

Tags: iphone

I have some contacts on my iPhone that's clearly duplicated. E.g. I have two James Fong contacts, one contains the person's home number and the other the person's mobile. Is there some software that can help me to combine them into one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here ya go buddy http://www.fixyourcontacts.com/

Comment: Or you can check out the KB article from Apple http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3677